# Is there buttons / funtion calls & tables handled in MetaWidget - js

Tags: metawidget

I am wondering if some can help me out to get the buttons , function calls and tables displayed using metawidget jsonSchema.

Unfortunately, I can see it just as a form render-er for our applications, is it something which we need to define externally? also if we could navigate from one form to another somehow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var mw = new metawidget.Metawidget( document.getElementById( 'metawidget' ), {

                inspector: new metawidget.inspector.CompositeInspector( [ new metawidget.inspector.PropertyTypeInspector(),
                    function( toInspect, type, names ) {

                        return {
                            properties:
                                name: {
                                    required: true
                                },
                                notes: {
                                    type: "string",
                                    large: true
                                },
                                employer: {
                                    type: "string",
                                    section: "Work"
                                },
                                department: {
                                    type: "string"
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    } ] ),

                layout: new metawidget.jqueryui.layout.TabLayoutDecorator(
                    new metawidget.layout.TableLayout( { numberOfColumns: 2 } ))
            } );        
            mw.toInspect = person;
            mw.buildWidgets();
```

Above schema holds only properties to render the fields, but where to specify the functionalities?

Comment: What have you done so far? Any samples or are you expecting to find someone to simply do it for you?

Comment: sorry, added in edits..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the object you are inspecting has functions, in JSON schema you can specify the property with a `type` of `function`. Metawidget will render these as buttons (and will wire up their click handler).

Note that `PropertyTypeInspector` will find functions automatically, so you could also consider combining your `JsonSchemaInspector` with a `PropertyTypeInspector` using `CompositeInspector`.

Often your data object (e.g. `var person = { firstname: 'Homer', surname: 'Simpson' }` ) and your actions object (e.g. `var personActions = { save: function() {...}, delete: function() {...}}` ) are separate. In those cases you can position two Metawidgets as siblings (or nested within each other), each pointing at different objects.

Finally for tables use a `type` of `array`. In JSON schema, you nest an `items` object that further nests a `properties` object, to describe the properties of the array items. See this example http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2016/04/metawidget-and-angular-arrays.html (it's for Angular, but the JSON Schema is the same)